# Creating sshKeys for gce instance using libcloud

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, libcloud

I need help! I am trying to create *sshKeys*(protocol pub_key username) for gce instance using libcloud API `create_node` with parameter `ex_metadata` while creating an instance. But username value is not getting saved when I check in google cloud console after the creation of instance.

Is there any different format to send *sshKeys* for metadata? I am sending data like this,

```
metadata = {"items": [{"value": value, "key": "sshKeys"}]}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with libcloud, however if you were using the [gcloud compute instances create](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create) and you want to pass SSH keys with the flag --metadata KEY=VALUE, you need to do it as

`-–metadata “sshKeys=username:ssh-rsaAAAAADAQABA....."`.

So it might be something like:

```
metadata = {"items": [{"value": username:ssh-rsaAAAAADAQABA....., "key": "sshKeys"}]}
```